# Logstash JDBC: Update row issue

Tags: elasticsearch, jdbc, logstash

Im using the Below JDBC code in Logstash for updating the already existing index in Elasticsearch, without duplicating rows or adding the updated row as another new row.
Versions: Elasticsearch, Logstash and Kibana are v7.1.0.

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:sqlserver://DB01:1433;databasename=testdb;integratedSecurity=true"
        jdbc_driver_class =>  "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    jdbc_driver_library => "C:\Program Files\sqljdbc_6.2\enu\mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar"
        jdbc_user => nil
        statement => "SELECT * from data WHERE updated_on > :sql_last_value ORDER BY updated_on"
    use_column_value =>true
        tracking_column =>updated_on
        tracking_column_type => "timestamp"
    }
}
output {
          elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"] 
        index => "datau" 
        action=>update
            document_id => "%{id}"
            doc_as_upsert =>true}
          stdout { codec => rubydebug }
       }
```

when i run the above in logstash (logstash -f myfile.conf)
the below error appars.

```
[2019-08-21T10:46:33,864][ERROR][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Failed to insta ll template. {:message=>"Got response code '400' contacting Elasticsearch at URL  'http://localhost:9200/_template/logstash'", :class=>"LogStash::Outputs::Elasti cSearch::HttpClient::Pool::BadResponseCodeError", :backtrace=>["D:/ELK 6.4.0/log stash-6.4.0/logstash-6.4.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-output-elasti csearch-9.2.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client/manticore_adap ter.rb:80:in `perform_request'", "D:/ELK 6.4.0/logstash-6.4.0/logstash-6.4.0/ven dor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-9.2.0-java/lib/logstas h/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client/pool.rb:291:in `perform_request_to_url'"...
```

Where am i gong wrong?

Comment: What version of Logstash and Elasticsearch are you running?

Comment: Elastic search 7.1.0 and Logstash 6.4.0. @Val

Comment: That's the issue! You need to use Logstash 7.1.0 or else the Elasticsearch index template that Logstash tries to install won't work.

Comment: @Val, Is ES 7.1.0 compatible with Logstash 7.0.0 instead? Im facing some issues with 7.1.0 Logstash.I get the following error: `Error: Could not find or load main class 7.1.0\logstash-7.0.0\logstash-7.0.0\log stash-core\lib\jars\animal-sniffer-annotations-1.14.jar;D:\ELK`

Comment: You can try Logstash 7.0.0, it should already work better than 6.4.0

Comment: I dont understand the cause of he main class error. While it works fine on 6.4.0, 7.0.0 and 7.1.0 shows this issue.

Comment: It doesn't work fine on 6.4.0 as we've seen. You probably have a JAVA_HOME or classpath issue... What Java version are you using `java -version`? Logstash 7+ requires Java 8 or 11

Comment: @val, actually, a normal data push via 6.4.0 is very much working. only the updation changes gave me this error. The below works in 6.4.0: `input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_connection_string => "......."
        jdbc_driver_class => "....."
    jdbc_driver_library => "C:\....\mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar"
        jdbc_user => nil
        statement => "SELECT * from data"
    }
}
output {
          elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"] 
        index => "datau" 
            }
          stdout { codec => rubydebug }
       }`

Comment: Im using Java 8

Comment: Still the 6.4.0 `logstash` index template errors out when being installed on ES 7.1.0, so that's not ideal and definitely not recommended.

Comment: I understand, any idea on fixing the main class error in this case? My JAVA_HOME and CLASS_PATH seem fine

Comment: How did you install Logstash 7.1.0? tarball, deb, rpm, zip, brew?

Comment: I used a Zip file @Val

Comment: I have a working logstash 7.1.0 now. @Val. But the error still remains the same.

Comment: Do you have the exact same error or a different one? Can you also add anything weird you see in the ES server log?

Comment: Sorry, my issue now is that any new column added comes along fine, any old column update isnt happening at all, no duplicates, no change too. I restarted elastic search,Kibana services to see it reflects too. but no luck. @Val

Comment: So at least the initial issue (version mismatches) has been resolved! now it's something completely different. You should close this question and create a new one with the new issue.

Comment: Thanks so much for helping through, ill start a separate chain for the new issue @Val

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the version compatibility.
I had used 6.4 logstash on 7.1 Elasticsearch.
Once my logstash was upgraded, the issue was resolved.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Remove `}` from this line:

```
doc_as_upsert =>true}
```